# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).accordion is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, accordion, jquery-migrate

Hi I am having an error on my Wordpress site and my Accordion menu is not working, 
Using: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/accordions/

`Uncaught TypeError: $(…).accordion is not a function.`

Could be being caused by jQuery versions, not entirely sure, my site was working fine yesterday and I have backtracked my changes and cannot find anything that was different.

Other errors I am getting are:

`jquery-migrate.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘migrateMute’ of undefined`

`selectize.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘extend’ of undefined`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for this kind of vague question.

I solved the problem. There was a defer added on the script tag for mc-validate.js (a mailchimp script) which was causing all the issues. I have no idea why but all problems went away.

Thanks